# How to register a View for Image content_type?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I've created and registered different views for different content types. They are working ok but only for content types other than Image and File. I cannot make the View available for the Image content type.

There is no Layout menu at all for Images. Nonetheless the Views appear in `/Plone/portal_view_customizations`:

```python
Products.ATContentTypes.content.document.ATDocument
    about-view (zope.publisher.interfaces.browser.IDefaultBrowserLayer)
Products.ATContentTypes.content.image.ATImage
    camera-view (zope.publisher.interfaces.browser.IDefaultBrowserLayer)
```

But `getAvailableLayouts` returns an empty list for the image and a non-empty list for the document:

```python
>>> image.getAvailableLayouts()
[]
>>> image.getTypeInfo().getAvailableViewMethods(image)
('image_view', 'camera-view')
>>> page.getAvailableLayouts()
[('about-view')]
>>> page.getTypeInfo().getAvailableViewMethods(page)
('document_view', 'about-view')
```

The following call in `getAvailableLayouts()` in `Products.CMFDynamicViewFTI-4.0.5-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFDynamicViewFTI/browserdefault.py` returns None

```python
view = zope.component.queryMultiAdapter((self, self.REQUEST),
                                         zope.interface.Interface, 
                                         name='image_view')
```

Any hints how to register Views for Image and File?

The coding is similar for all my views and is reproduced here (examples for Document and Image):

In `/browser/configure.zcml`

```xml
<browser:page
    for="Products.ATContentTypes.content.image.ATImage"
    name="camera-view"
    class=".camera_view.CameraView"
    permission="zope2.View"
    template="camera_view.pt"
    />

<browser:page
    for="Products.ATContentTypes.content.document.ATDocument"
    name="about-view"
    class=".about_view.AboutView"
    permission="zope2.View"
    template="about_view.pt"
    />
```

In `/browser/about_view.py`

```python
from Products.Five import BrowserView
class AboutView(BrowserView):
    """ """
```

In `/profiles/default/types/Document.xml`

```xml
<object name="Document">
    <property name="view_methods" purge="False">
        <element value="about-view"/>
    </property>
</object>
```

In `/browser/camera_view.py`

```python
from Products.Five import BrowserView
class CameraView(BrowserView):
    """ """
```

In `/profiles/default/types/Image.xml`

```xml
<object name="Image">
    <property name="view_methods" purge="False">
        <element value="camera-view"/>
    </property>
</object>
```

In `/profiles/default/types.xml`

```xml
<object name="portal_types" meta_type="Plone Types Tool">
    <object name="Document" meta_type="Factory-based Type Information with dynamic views"/>
    <object name="Image" meta_type="Factory-based Type Information with dynamic views"/>
</object>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Plone 4 images (and files) are blob-based and are actually instances of ATBlob from plone.app.blob, rather than ATImage.

You should register your view for the plone.app.blob.interfaces.IATBlobImage interface, which is used as a marker on blobs that are images, rather than for the ATImage class.

Comment: Thank you very much! After reading the class definition of `ATBlob` I can't beliebe that `__repr__()` was modified to `replace(ATBlob.__name__, 'ATImage', 1)`. This drove me nuts for a while. The Plone Lord moves in mysterious ways. ;-)

Comment: Oh dear, that's pretty bad. I think that was witsch trying to keep the existing tests passing with the new implementation.